# Regex: Match Characters After Multiple Underscores but not including Underscore

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to get the first letter of every new word in the following string.

```
hello_world! hello___America! software-developer **for_life!?**
```

I've put together the following regex that almost gets there:

```
(\b\w|(?=)_[^_])
```

The problem is that it also copies the underscore preceding the next word.

See screenshot:
[image]

I want the letter after the underscore (or chain of underscores), plus the first letter of all of the other words that I already have highlighted with that regex pattern.

The answer I'm looking for should be abstract enough to capture letters/numbers/words split between one or more underscores.

Here's the [Rubular shortlink](http://rubular.com/r/6ON03maXNr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may perhaps use a *[positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* assertion ...

```
\b\w|(?<=_)[^_]
     ^^^^^^
```

see **[demo on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/E8NXEfi4Hb)**